# What is the data type for data extract by gsutil tool from Google Play

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, gsutil

I’m using **gsutil tool** to pull my application data from Google Play and import this data to my database.

I pull the data in **CSV** format and the result is a file like this:
[image]

I need to know what the **data type** is of this information?

Like the "`Daily Device Installs`", what type is it?

- What is the **max length**?
- What is the **min length**?
- What is the type of **encoding** ? UTF-8?

I think this information will help me to define my database attribute type.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **most** of the fields you mentioned are described here, under "Commands & file formats for aggregated reports" > "Statistics" > "Installs" > "File Format":

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en

And based on this paragraph, the file is UTF-16 encoded:

> Tip: If you want to import your reports from Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery, you need to convert the CSV files from UTF-16 to UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you for your reply it is really helpful but i want to ask please is there is any thing about the length for the string and int thank you